# How can I send messages to users inboxes using the Oauth-linkedin gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api, omniauth, sendmessage

I have an application that uses the Linkedin API helpers and currently I am able to fetch "people" data, using the get method and the endpoint address (e.g. "/v1/people/~/connections"), which returns in this case the XML containing the authenticated user friends.

> [13] myapp »  u = User.find(3)
>
> [14] myapp »  u.linkedin.get("/v1/people/~/connections").body

```
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<connections total=\"457\" count=\"455\" start=\"0\">\n (...)
```

However, I am not able to send messages; despite having the flag w_messages, it keep returning a 401 error, Not Authorized, even when I try to send a message to myself (where MYUSERID=numeric 7 digit id):

```
[15] myapp »  u.linkedin.post('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox', '<mailbox-item> <recipients> <recipient> <person path="/people/~"/> </recipient> <recipient> <person path="/people/MYUSERID" /> </recipient> </recipients> <subject>Congratulations on your new position.</subject> <body>You are certainly the best person for the job!</body> </mailbox-item>').body


=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<error>\n  <status>401</status>\n  <timestamp>1383661453052</timestamp>\n  <request-id>T36BEYPC1T</request-id>\n  <error-code>0</error-code>\n  <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:4weqo9zxt1zt|abcdefg-efgh-ijkl-mnop-14875f6dad97|*01|*01:1383661458:8du6NgLjwZTRDzTexg/fJcZCiBY=</message>\n</error>\n"
```

I tried variations and combinations, trying to use the UID (symbolic ID), but no success. I also read the full linkedin documentation on Send Messages, tried send it on JSON, searched for forums such as stackoverflow but couldn't find anyone who has actually send messages using the posts.

Can anyone help me? Is there any parameter in the header that needs to be set? How can I do that?

Thanks and regards

PS: My environment is the following:
Rails 3
ruby-1.9.3-p362
gem "omniauth-linkedin"